# Thrift call over socks_proxy

Tags: thrift, socks

Does thrift have support for socks proxy? Currently my client and server process are on same machine so i do something like

```
TTransport transport;
transport = new TSocket("localhost", port);
transport.open();
```

Now I need to move my thrift client to a separate machine where access to machine running thrift server is only via a tunnel machine.